# social network icons are not displaying center in android

Tags: android, xml

Hi in the below xml code facebook,linkin,logo not displaying center .Can any one help me where did wrong.Why those 3 icons are not displaying center.customized login screen I have designed and used gravity to center_horizontal but it is not working properly.below one is login screen contains username and password with login button

Can any one help me to resolve the issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_background">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20.7dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="630dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/White"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:hint="USERNAME"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:padding="20dp"
                        android:textColorHint="#606060"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:hint="PASSWORD"
                        android:drawableTint="@color/linecolor"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:padding="20dp"
                        android:textColorHint="#606060"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/login"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                        android:text="LOGIN"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:id="@+id/facebook"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:id="@+id/linkedin"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/linkedin" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:id="@+id/gen_logo"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/gen_logo"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="GenWorks"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/linecolor"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Opportunity Management"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/linecolor"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign weight on each Linear Layout. Below implementation will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_background">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/White"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="USERNAME"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#606060"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="PASSWORD"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/linecolor"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#606060"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_msg_from"
                    android:text="LOGIN"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

             <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/fb" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/linkedin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:src="@drawable/linkedin" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/gen_logo"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gen_logo"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="GenWorks"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/uidBlackShade"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Opportunity Management"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/uidDarkBlack"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how to give exact screen digonally

Comment: can u elaborate what u want further? as according to your query what i understand is to allign your social media icons in diagonal way.